# При подключении API Telegram к node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Установил программу Node.js, потом создал папку, установил в нее сервер nvm (команда npm init), далее туда же установил библиотеку для взаимодействия с API Telegram (команда npm install --save node-telegram-bot-api), далее написал код:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

// replace the value below with the Telegram token you receive from @BotFather
const token = '111111111:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

// Create a bot that uses 'polling' to fetch new updates
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

// Matches "/echo [whatever]"
bot.onText(/\/echo (.+)/, (msg, match) => {
  // 'msg' is the received Message from Telegram
  // 'match' is the result of executing the regexp above on the text content
  // of the message

  const chatId = msg.chat.id;
  const resp = match[1]; // the captured "whatever"

  // send back the matched "whatever" to the chat
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, resp);
});

// Listen for any kind of message. There are different kinds of
// messages.
bot.on('message', (msg) => {
  const chatId = msg.chat.id;

  // send a message to the chat acknowledging receipt of their message
  bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Received your message');
});
```

Потом выводит ошибку, **но бот работает:**

> node-telegram-bot-api deprecated Automatic enabling of cancellation of promises
>   is deprecated.
>   In the future, you will have to enable it yourself.
>   See https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/issues/319. module.js:652:30

Comment: Это не ошибка, это предупреждение. И в нём более-менее описано, что с ним делать. Попробуйте перевести его на русский язык или сходить по ссылке и перевести что там.

Comment: как не странно, но перепробовал всё, кроме инструкции в этом предупреждении, так как не понял его вообще, если кто-то понял прошу помочь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не ошибка! Данная строка вываливается всегда при включении..

Comment: просто я не видел эту строку ни в одном обучающем видео

Answer (score 0):

Для устранения сообщения добавь в process.env следующий параметр:

```
process.env.NTBA_FIX_319 = 1;
```